# Can SQL PIVOT do such transformation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

My data looks like

```
+-------+-------+-------+------+
| Group | Count | Month | Year |
+-------+-------+-------+------+
| A     |   102 | Jan   | 2015 |
| B     |    20 | Jan   | 2016 |
| C     |    30 | Feb   | 2015 |
| A     |    10 | Jan   | 2016 |
| C     |    20 | Feb   | 2016 |
+-------+-------+-------+------+
```

I want the output like

```
+-------+-------+------+-------+
| Group | Month | 2015 |  2016 |
+-------+-------+------+-------+
| A     | Jan   |   102|    10 |
| B     | Jan   |   20 |     0 |
| C     | Feb   |   30 |    20 |
+-------+-------+------+-------+
```

I tried using PIVOT but I'm not sure if it will show the outcome as I want.

The below query is a poor attempt by me (doesn't work)-

```
SELECT 'Total' AS Total, 
    [2015], [2016]
    FROM
    (SELECT DATENAME(YEAR,[mydate]) as Y, Datename(month,[mydate]) as M
     FROM incidents) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
     count(DATENAME(YEAR,[mydate]))
     FOR DATENAME(YEAR,[mydate]) IN (2015,2016)
    ) AS PivotTable;
```

My date column is in this format `2016-01-20 03:00:11.000`. I use `MONTH()` and `DATENAME` function to extract month number and name.

Comment: In your proposed result, shouldn't be the group `A` for year 2015 be `102` and for 2016 `10`?

Comment: Add all columns you need to select list of your `sourcetable`. And outside of this subselect you don't need to get `datename` again - you already have Y and M columns there.

Comment: @IvanSivak Yes. Corrected Now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
WITH Src AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    ('A',102, 'Jan', 2015),
    ('B', 20, 'Jan', 2016),
    ('C', 30, 'Feb', 2015),
    ('A', 10, 'Jan', 2016),
    ('C', 20, 'Feb', 2016)) T([Group], Count, Month, Year)
)
SELECT [Group],Month,ISNULL([2015],0) [2015],ISNULL([2016],0) [2016] FROM Src
PIVOT
(SUM(Count) FOR Year IN ([2015], [2016])) AS Pvt
ORDER BY [Group],Month
```

Comment: Worked like a charm ! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There's really no need for the actual `pivot` operation.

```
select
    "Group", "Month",
    case when "Year" = 2015 then sum("Count") end as "2015",
    case when "Year" = 2016 then sum("Count") end as "2016"
from incidents
group by "Group", "Month"
```

The `sum()` aggregate is just a dummy function with this sample data. It could just as easily be `min()` or `max()` or `avg()` even.